# Decorating the pull request in GitHub with SonarQube (Community Edition)

Tags: github, sonarqube, github-actions, sonarqube-7.9

Firstly I created SonarQube Server (Community Edition)
and I integrated sonarQube with Github for scanning the code of the GitHub.

Then, I Created action in GitHub to run the sonarQube

> .github/workflows/python-pull.yml

```
 run: sonar-scanner
          -Dsonar.host.url=${{ secrets.SONAR_URL }}
          -Dsonar.login=${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          -Dsonar.projectKey=${{ secrets.SONAR_PROJECT_KEY }}
          -Dsonar.pullrequest.key=${{ github.event.number }}
          -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=${{ github.HEAD_REF }}
          -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=${{ github.BASE_REF }}
          -Dsonar.pullrequest.github.repository=${{ github.repository }}
          -Dsonar.scm.provider=git
          -Dsonar.java.binaries=/tmp
```

[The result of GitHub actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uclbP.png)
In this image, It showed only "All checks have passed"

Whenever I do push or pull in the  GitHub so sonarQube server shows all the bugs, errors, Vulnerabilities, etc.[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RguOO.png)

**But my requirement is:**
I want all details of the code will display on the GitHub page which is shows in Sonarqube Server (Like bugs and errors)

And also let me know that
Is it possible in the community Edition of sonarQube?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Decorating Pull Request is for Developer edition or above.

But you can use unofficial release [sonarqube-community-branch-plugin](https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin)

Install this plugin and then you can refer to documentation for further configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Decorating Pull Reauest is not available for Community Edition.
It is available from Developer Edition and above.

Check the sonarsource documentation available for more information.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/pull-request/

https://www.sonarqube.org/github-integration/